# Why is WPF NotifyIcon Icon property setter throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, notifyicon

I'm having trouble with a NotifyIcon in WPF, the second line is throwing an exception. I can't seem to find a way to use the icon file I have in the resources, can anyone help.

```
notifyI = new NotifyIcon();
notifyI.Icon = new Icon("Power.ico");
notifyI.Text = "Shutdown Timer";
notifyI.Visible = true;
notifyI.MouseDoubleClick += new
System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(notifyI_MouseDoubleClick);
```

Comment: What exception is it throwing?

Comment: In my case it was FileNotFoundException. Hans answer below sorted it out for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Icon(string) constructor looks for a file *on disk* for the icon file, it doesn't look in a resource.  Consider using the Icon(Stream) constructor instead.

Or use Project + Properties, Resource tab, arrow on Add Resource button, Add Existing File.  Select your .ico file.  Then you'd use it like this:

```
 notifyI.Icon = Properties.Resources.Power;
```